# sql query to display the customer id and the maximum number of orders placed by the customer. Give an alias name as 'MAX_COUNT'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

[Please see database structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkgLc.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 0):

Please post some code next Time.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as ‘Maxcount’, cust_id from Orders 
GROUP BY cust_id
ORDER BY cust_id;
```